# How to connect wifi thermostat with a boiler after cable upgrade?

Tags: thermostat, boiler, thermostat-c-wire

I have an old battery operated thermostat right now with two wires (18/2) attached to it running to a boiler. No AC, fan, etc.-- just a boiler. I can easily replace the wire with 18/5 one, however I'm unsure how to later attach the wires inside the boiler and to then Honeywell wifi thermostat.

Wires inside the boiler:

[image]

The thermosat is a Honeywell RTH8580WF.

Comment: You can see standard color markings on the terminal plate (W, G, etc.). I'd make those connections and then connect your new thermostat according to the instructions provided.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to guess but here's what it looks like:

- The top left post `1`, Thick yellow wire is boiler
- The top middle post `2`, labeled `G` activates both the fan (thin black wire) and the boiler (thin red wire jumping `1` and `2`)
- The bottom left post `4`, Thick white wire is neutral `C`
- The bottom right post `5`, Thick black wire is hot `R`

There is no fan delay control so when the thermostat shorts the red and white, it energises both fan and boiler.

With 18/5 wire you'll connect

- `White` to top center post: Call for heat `W`
- `Red` to bottom right post: Hot `R`
- `Blue` to bottom left post: Neutral `C`
- `Green` unconnected: fan control `G`
- `Yellow` unconnected: call for cool `Y`

Important: The RTH8580WF is made for 24VAC systems.  **If the boiler is using line voltage (120V) it will destroy the thermostat.**